# WordPress plugin development with PhpStorm

Tags: wordpress, testing, plugins, phpstorm

Hello dear Community I need help

I would like to start programming WordPress plugins.
I use PhpStorm for this.

I followed the instructions on JetBrains.com and I do not know how to debug the plugin.

[image: Php-Settings]

[image: Directories-Settings]

I want to test the plugin without copying it into the WordPress core.

Comment: Side note: maybe WordPress specific section will be better? (no idea on how many PhpStorm-specific/related questions can be found there though) https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you check Wordpress development guide - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/WordPress+Development+using+PhpStorm ?
Basically debugging WP code is same as debugging any other PHP code, we just need to have WP core added to Include Path.